# I am looking for a specific recitation of the Qur'an (Surah Hamd) with Arabic accent, without singing

Tags: surah

I am looking for a specific recitation of the Qur'an (especially Surah Ekhlas or Hamd and Tohid) with Arabic accent, without singing (and that tune just unlike Abdul Basit's recitation which you know some kind of melodies and music and that voice).
I just want a simple Arabic dialect, Arabic sounds like someone who's reading important lyrics (without singing) like [this](https://www.roshd.ir/DesktopModules/Barrizon/LArticle/api/File/Get/628ff343-2b92-426c-bbe7-0216e20ea93e?download=true).

I hope that I have been able to express my meaning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check **[Surah Ikhlas](http://pureislamic.com/qurans/112)** from this web application. They've got it with various recitations including multiple language translations option.